# repaint() method in Java will not repaint my Rectangle after translation

Tags: java, components, repaint

I;m making a game in which I have to move little squares on an n by n grid, and they have to transition smoothly. This is the swap method I made which should be able to paint my transition on screen, but for some reason it is not doing it. I tried a much simpler version of my code on a simple project to move a Square back and forth and it worked like a charm, so I'm really not sure why this isn't repainting. This is just a bit of my code so if there's doubts about anything else on my code, ask away.

Thanks in advance. (:

```
public void swap( int y,  int x ) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int counter = 0;
    swapNum = tiles[y][x];
    rect = (Rectangle) rectangles[y][x].clone();

    while(counter < rect.height) {
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - time > 5) {
        rect.translate(this.y-y, this.x-x);
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        counter++;
        repaint();

        }

    }
    swapNum = 0;
    rect = new Rectangle();


    int temporary = tiles[this.y][this.x];
    tiles[this.y][this.x] = tiles[y][x];
    tiles[y][x] = temporary;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this block of code is running on the Event/Dispatch thread, which is used for drawing to the screen, then this will block the screen from updating.

Instead of doing the entire animation in one loop, consider designing an update method to do the animation, that will be called once every 15-30 milliseconds, and update the rectangle's position accordingly. Even better for smooth graphics is to draw to an image buffer and then have the actual draw method paint that buffer to the screen (double buffering).

Java3D has animations built-in, so it may be worth a look.